# How to remove extra letters added to section name using \verb with htlatex?

Tags: tex4ht

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\begin{document}
\cprotect\section{\verb|invlaplace(exp((a*s)^(1/2)), s, t)|}
test
\end{document}
```

pdflatex output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but `htlatex foo.tex` generated this HTML output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html > 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)"> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)"> 
<!-- html --> 
<meta name="src" content="foo.tex"> 
<meta name="date" content="2013-11-16 02:34:00"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo.css"> 
</head><body 
>
   <h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">1   </span> <a 
 id="x1-10001"></a><span class="obeylines-h"><span class="verb"><span 
class="cmtt-10">invlaplace(exp((a*s)^(1/2)),</span><span 
class="cmtt-10">&#x00A0;s,</span><span 
class="cmtt-10">&#x00A0;t)</span></span></span>&#x02C6;&#x02C6;E&#x02C6;&#x02C6;L </h3>
<!--l. 6--><p class="noindent" >test

</body></html>
```

How can one remove the extra  `^^E^^L`  noise added?
Using `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need to use the `cprotect` package? As  simple workaround, you can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\section{\protect\Verb|invlaplace(exp((a*s)^(1/2)), s, t)|}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. No I do not need to. I tried `\texttt` and that did not work due to `^` being there. So I tried `cprotect`. I tried your solution and it worked!